# Why this % Error in Ruby ? Beginner Learning

Tags: ruby, primes

I just began with Ruby yesterday.
I saw some basics online and started to do some beginner coding challenges and one asks for finding prime numbers. I try not using the prime feature already in Ruby.
I think I almost have it, but I don't understand why the error shows itself.

"18:in ': undefined method %' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

I tried to tweak around it for a few hours now, and can't seem to find solutions to this online...
I use Ruby 3.0.0, here's the code I managed to build until now:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
prime_nums = []
i = 0

#Loop on the array to check each element
while i <= nums.length
  check = 0
  divider = nums[i]

  #While to prevent DivisionByZero error
  while divider != 0
    if nums[i] % divider == 0    #/!\ ERROR HERE
      check += 1
    end
    divider -= 1
  end
  #Only division by 1 and itself will increment $check
  if check == 2
    prime_nums.append(nums[i])
  end
  i += 1
end
puts prime_nums
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example it means that `nums[i]` returns nil, so the case is that `i` is greater than 19.

You can change `while i <= nums.length` to `while i < nums.length` because arrays are indexed from 0 in Ruby.

Comment: That was it, omg.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`undefined method %' for nil:NilClass` means you're trying to use `%` on `nil`. `nil` is what you get when you, for example, try to get too much out of an Array.

If we put `p "#{i}: #{nums[i]}"` in the loop we'll see that `i` goes to 20. Arrays start counting at 0, so if you have 20 elements in an array the highest index is 19. `num[20]` is `nil`.

You can fix this with `while i < nums.length` to stop at 19.

However, one rarely writes `while` loops in Ruby. Instead, you iterate using methods. [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each) iterates through each element of an Array. And you can count down with [`downto`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-downto).

```
nums.each do |num|
  check = 0

  num.downto(1) do |divider|
    if num % divider == 0
      check += 1
    end
  end

  #Only division by 1 and itself will increment $check
  if check == 2
    prime_nums.append(num)
  end
end
```

Now there's no chance of being off-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Schwern has great advice on using iterating methods in Ruby. We can use them to make your algorithm much more efficient.

```
def is_prime?(num)
  2.upto Math::sqrt(num) do |divisor|
    return false if num % divisor == 0
  end

  true
end
```

Rather than iterate down from `num` to `1` and keep track of divisors, we can start from `2` and work up to the square root of `num`. If we find an even divisor, we know it's not prime and can immediately return `false`, saving ourselves the effort of iterating over anything further.

If we reach the end of the loop, we know `num` must be prime and return `true`.

Then let's say we want to print primes from `1` to `500`, we can do:

```
1.upto 500 do |num|
  puts num if is_prime? num
end
```